# Eliminating Website Horizontal Scroll

Tags: web

I have been changing lots of things to my website and now I somehow have created it to not fit to screen and has a tiny scroll to the right. Can someone see the issue that is causing this.

Looking to get rid of the black on the right hand side. Only the top and bottom should be black.

www.jobspark.ca is the website

[image]

UPDATE
So this is the line of code that is causing the black space. But when I remove the 100% the image shrinks back to fit into the 960px site width. Any ideas? im ready to give up haha Squarespace is not easy to modify

```
#collection-513d5347e4b0abff73be5267  #site > .wrapper {
max-width: 100%;
padding: 0 0px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you you have `width:100%` on your div elements, this forces the client area of each element to fill the browser. Now since the elements' borders add an additional pixel on each side, you end up with a scrollbar.

I would recommend that you omit `width:100%` from your div elements. It should auto expand to 100% of it's parent and that should solve your problems.

If all fails this should work,

```
overflow-y: auto; // or replace auto with scroll
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: I think you are on to something. I edited my question and added some of the css for that page that is causing the issue. Maybe u can pick something up from it

Comment: @ChrisS Have you tried taking the `width` off the `#collection-513d5347e4b0abff73be5267  #site > .wrapper` ?

Comment: @ Also `position: relative;` from the same element is saving no purpose. Read more about positioning here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp